# Вычислите количество четных, нечетных и простых чисел в заданном диапазоне. Python

Tags: python

```
lower = int(input())
upper = int(input())
odd = 0
even = 0
prima = 0
for i in range(lower, upper+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1

    if i > 1:
        for j in range(2, i):
            if (i % j) == 0:
                break
            else:
                prima += 1

print(prima, even, odd)
```

Я написала вот такой код. Что касается нечётных и чётных чисел - всё работает. А вот с простыми числами выдаёт неправильный ответ. Подскажите в чём проблема. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно изменить условие для проверки на простоту числа. Раньше вы считали число правильным сразу, если оно не делилось на 2.

По сути надо написать блок `else` для цикла, то есть удалить по знаку табуляции на 2 строках. Так будет работать:

```
upper = int(input())
odd = 0
even = 0
prima = 0
for i in range(lower, upper+1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        even += 1
    else:
        odd += 1

    if i > 1:
        for j in range(2, i):
            if (i % j) == 0:
                break
        else:
            prima += 1

print(prima, even, odd)
```

P.S. Для проверки числа на простоту достаточно перебирать только от 2 до квадратного корня этого числа